# Vlookup cell background colour from another workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, colors, vlookup

So I have a Gant chart like workbook that has a unique number for each worker (representing a row) then I want to retrieve the cell color from this row and a specified column, much like a normal vlookup. see image below.

[image]

I want this green to be picked up in the cell corresponding to the day i.e. the column and the row i.e. Job no.

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to do this with VBA - a formula can't copy a color.  Have you tried some VBA to solve this?  It's not really clear from your screenshot where the input is, or what determines which cells on the row are colored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing but since i have this code anyway...

```
Function Tester(rngLookup As Range, v)
    Dim c As Range, f As Range, clr As Long

    Set c = Application.ThisCell '<< the cell with the formula
    Set f = rngLookup.Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        clr = f.Interior.Color
    Else
        clr = vbWhite
    End If
    'change the background for the cell with the formula
    Application.Evaluate "ChangeColor(""" & c.Parent.Name & """,""" & c.Address() & """," & clr & ")"
    Tester = v 'or whatever is appropriate...
End Function

Sub ChangeColor(sht As String, addr As String, clr As Long)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range(addr).Interior.Color = clr
End Sub
```

Example usage (with show formulas enabled):

[image]